# what is "logic of computable functions"?

Tags: logic, isabelle

wiki explains it as

> Logic for Computable Functions (LCF) is an interactive automated theorem prover developed at Stanford and Edinburgh by Robin Milner and collaborators in early 1970s, based on the theoretical foundation of logic of computable functions previously proposed by Dana Scott.

I know LCF from Isabelle Theorem Prover and not clear about the relationship between logic and computable functions.

1. what's computable functions?
2. what's the relationship between logic and computable functions?
3. what's the LCF-style?

Comment: The following links/papers should address most of your concerns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_of_Computable_Functions, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759390095B, https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/archive/mjcg/papers/HolHistory.html, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02836.pdf (I hope).